# MyEclipse doesn' t Connect to the pulse server

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

I installed MyEclipse 10.7.1 instance. I am trying to install subclipse plug in from MyEclipse Configuration Center, but when i click on plugin added in Personal Site i obtain error . I see that in "About This Profile" tab sync state is Disconnected. If i try to **sync now** link MyEclipse shows confirm popup "Would you like to open the Pulse Communication Wizard?", i press Yes but MyEclipse doens't works. It gives me **HTTP error occured(301). Unexpected failure:EOFException, pulse has received an error talking to the server at 
        https://www.poweredbypulse.com:443
;an unexpected network error occured attempting to connect to the server. The error is EOFException :null
I use Window 7 and MyEclipse 10.7.1 (64 bit installation).**

Am struck with this since almost 3 weeks but could not figure it out, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10.7.1 isn't fully supported any more; maybe the pulse servers don't have versions for that release. You'd definitely be better off installing the latest GA (release 2014) or the latest interim (release 2015 CI). You don't have to deal with the config center then, either! There may be a way to get what you want with 10.x but getting a later release is the recommended solution.